# Can 2 web views are allowed to be used at a time on single activity?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

i was converting my website and my youtube channel in app
this app have two activity haves two different `webview` when click button for second `webview` then unfortunately stopped . and second activity have almost same coding

```
 {package com.example.cybercry.cybercry;



   private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pubxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    AdView ads=(AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

    AdRequest adRequest= new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    ads.loadAd(adRequest);
    prepareAds();
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
            Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            Log.i("hello", "world");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        interstitialAd.show();
                    } else {
                        Log.d("TAG"," Interstitial not loaded");
                    }

                    prepareAds();


                }
            });

        }
    }, 30, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}

public  void onclick()
{   Intent cintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,webiste.class);
        startActivity(cintent);
    }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
public void prepareAds(){
    interstitialAd= new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    AdRequest adRequest= new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}

}
```

Comment: Did not understand at all. What is your question?

Comment: Post your crash log